# GoogleApiClient is not configured to use LocationServices.API required for this call

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api

I'm building an Android app that finds and displays locations of nearest pharmacies and their details in a custom info window. When I run the app it is able to launch but after clicking on the button that will display the nearest pharmacies but the app crashed so I checked the Logcat and found this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use LocationServices.API required for this call.

I don't know if its this part of the code that is creating this error

```
Button btnPharma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPharma);
    btnPharma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        String search = "pharmacy";

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){

            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, search);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            GetNearbyBanksData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyBanksData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(pharma2.this, "These are your Nearby Pharmacies! ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This is the button for the class that performs the displaying of the nearest pharmacies.

this is the Logcat error lines

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use LocationServices.API required for this call.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbd.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbym.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.sachiewerk.smart_healthcare.pharma2.onConnected(pharma2.java:304)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzad.zzk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbd.zzj(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.zzahc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzajo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzajp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: did you add the proper configuration in the manifest file? developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

Comment: Yeah, the manifest file configuration was checked and its okay. I exceeded the
 post character limit so couldn't add the manifest file.

Comment: There is rather too much code here for people to wade through. I suggest you cut it down into a more manageable example, in other words a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two differents `GoogleApiClient` instances: one for `LocationServices` API and another for `Places` API.